# Interlocked.Increment *with* [ThreadStatic]?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

When I intend to increment a static `int` per thread safely, all I need to do is mark that static field `[ThreadStatic]`, right?

```cs
public static class MyClass
{
  public static int GetOrdinal() => ++myInt;

  [ThreadStatic]
  private static int myInt;
}
```

Based on my intent, is this overkill?:

```cs
public static class MyClass
{
  public static int GetOrdinal() => Interlocked.Increment(myInt);

  [ThreadStatic]
  private static int myInt;
}
```

Comment: A `ThreadStatic` field isn't shared between threads so you don't need `Interlocked.Increment` for it.

Comment: Per [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?view=netframework-4.8) _Each executing thread has a separate instance of the field, and independently sets and gets values for that field. If the field is accessed on a different thread, it will contain a different value._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your first question, yes that is all you have to do. No locking is required because all access to your `int` is serialized (by definition) on that running thread.

So, in answer to your second question, yes that is overkill. Replace

```
public static int GetOrdinal() => Interlocked.Increment(myInt);
```

with

```
public static int GetOrdinal() => myInt++;
```